# SSL Certificate Issue - "Data Transfer Interrupted"

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, ssl, certificate

I imported a PFX file for a dedicated SSL Certificate from 1and1 for a domain on my web server.

When I visit the domain, I get the message "Data Transfer Interrupted"

I need help debugging this.

What should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having had this issue in the past the best advice I can offer is to redeploy the cert again.  Are you using IIS to deploy the cert to a group of servers?  I have had issues with that and I re-deployed the cert using IIS's mechanism to push the cert to other servers.

If that doesn't work there are some fairly decent SSL debugging tools from MS.  http://www.iis.net/downloads/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1251 is one of the best.

The last item that I can think of could be an issue with the SSL cert chain.  Sometimes with non-tier 1 SSL providers there are intermediate certs that have to be installed on your certificate repository.